# How to Toggle Two Elements Simultaneously Using Pure JS

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am trying to figure out how to toggle two elements at the same time:

One element fades-in while another fades-out which works fine, but I also need to change/add a class to another element. Basically I have a nav menu that hides and shows div's but I also need to highlight the links and do it all in pure vanilla JavaScript. I was thinking [hoping] to execute it using the `element.toggle` class.

Any help is appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <section class="" id="home">
        <p>...Stuff</p>
    </section>

    <section class="" id="about">
        <p>...Stuff</p>
    </section>

    <section class="" id="contact">
        <p>...Stuff</p>
    </section>

    <div>
        <a href="javascript:toggle('home', 'home-btn')" id="home-lnk" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="javascript:toggle('about', 'about-btn')" id="about-lnk">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:toggle('contact', 'contact-btn')" id="contact-lnk">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**
**EDIT:** *Currently the div's toggle but the link highlights the wrong link*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var divs = [ "home", "about", "contact" ];
    var lnks = [ "home-lnk", "about-lnk", "contact-lnk" ]

    function toggle(layer) {
        var d, l
        for(var i = 0; i < divs.length && lnks.length; i += 1) {

            d = document.getElementById(divs[i]);
            d.style.opacity = '0';

            l = document.getElementById(lnks[i]);
            l.className = '';
        }

        d = document.getElementById(layer);
        d.style.transition = 'opacity 1s';
        d.style.opacity = '1';

        l = document.getElementById(lnks[i]);
        l.className += 'active';
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Easy!**

I was missing the semicolon after:

```
var lnks = [ "home-lnk", "about-lnk", "contact-lnk" ];
```